# Modify notification from FCM / onMessageReceived not called when app is in background

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, push-notification, react-native-fcm

I'm building an app in react native, and I attached `react-native-fcm` library to the code, in order to work with notification messages.

I have two main problems:

1) Notification from the `firebase` doesn't look like the ordinary notification messages: it's not appear with app icon, it doesn't popup and presented when the screen is closed.

2) I wanted just to get the event of messaging, also here after reviewing the  library code, I saw that notification get to the function: `onMessageReceived` only if the app on foreground, like it say in the website.
But in the website I couldn't understand how to get the general event of catching notificaiton regardless to the appstate.
I also tried to implement class that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`, and there the notification doesn't get to the `onMessageReceived` override at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use FCM API and send data in `data` field instead of using Firebase console or `notification` field so that the method `onMessageReceived` is always called regardless of whether the app is in foreground or background. When this method is called, you can create a notification as you like.

Read about FCM admin API at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/

Read about FCM HTTP API at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

You can use Postman to send notification if you choose to use FCM HTTP API.